# Qt: Multithreading connect does not work

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I want to connect two threads. One Thread is the Mainthread of my application the other on is a workerthread. I have based my code on the following example [doc.qt.io/qt-5/](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#QThread). For me it does not work completely. I am sending a QString to my WorkerThread (this works) and want to send it afterwards back to the MainThread (does not work). Before asking why I am doing this that's just a very simple example. The real Code is much more complex but I have exactly the same problem. If those example would run I am very sure that the complex one would work too. Here the code:

Main.cpp

```
#include "Controller_C.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Controller_C Controller;
    Controller.SendData("Hello World!");
    return a.exec();
}
```

Controller_C.cpp

```
#include "Controller_C.h"
#include <qmessagebox.h>

Controller_C::Controller_C(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent),
      Worker(new Worker_C())
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    Worker->moveToThread(&WorkerThread);
    connect(&WorkerThread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(ThreadStarted()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(SendToWorker(QString)), Worker, SLOT(DoWork(QString)));
    connect(Worker, SIGNAL(SendToController()), this, SLOT(ReceiveData()));
    WorkerThread.start();
}

Controller_C::~Controller_C()
{

}

void Controller_C::SendData(QString aString)
{
    QThread* Controller = QThread::currentThread();
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", QString("We have send the following to the Worker Thread: %1").arg(aString));
    emit SendToWorker(aString);
}

void Controller_C::ReceiveData(QString aString)
{
    QThread* Controller = QThread::currentThread();
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", QString("The Controller received the following: %1").arg(aString));
}
```

Controller_C.h

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_C_H
#define CONTROLLER_C_H

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_Controller_C.h"
#include "Worker_C.h"
#include <qthread.h>

class Controller_C : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Controller_C(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Controller_C();

    void SendData(QString aString);

private:
    Ui::Qt_TestEnvironmentClass     ui;
    Worker_C*                       Worker;
    QThread                         WorkerThread;

signals:

    void SendToWorker(QString);

public slots:

    void ReceiveData(QString aString);
};

#endif // CONTROLLER_C_H
```

Worker_C.cpp

```
#include "Worker_C.h"
#include <qmessagebox.h>
#include <qthread.h>

Worker_C::Worker_C()
{

}

Worker_C::~Worker_C()
{

}

void Worker_C::DoWork(QString aString)
{
    QThread* Worker = QThread::currentThread();
    emit SendToController(aString);
}
```

Worker_C.h

```
#ifndef WORKER_C_H
#define WORKER_C_H

#include <QObject>

class Worker_C : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Worker_C();
    ~Worker_C();

public slots:

    void DoWork(QString aString);

signals:

    void SendToController(QString);

};

#endif // WORKER_C_H
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your `connect` call for the worker signal, the `QString` argument is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the way you definied the Slot/Signal in your header:

> void ReceiveData(QString aString);
>   void SendToController(QString);

You should also use them like this in your connect:

```
connect(Worker, SIGNAL(SendToController(QString)), this, SLOT(ReceiveData(QString)));`
```

Comment: "I would suggest you to use QApplication::processEvents() in your more complex code if you emit many signals." That's bad advice. It only makes sense if your code is already broken. If you think you need `processEvents`, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: You need `processEvents` in some UI applications with long-running process having actual pending events (for updating the GUI). I think there are some few applications for `processEvents` but I also have to admit that calling `processEvents` should not be the first option. I will remove it from my awnser.

Comment: There are no long-running processes in the GUI thread. If there are, it's already broken.